# Unable to delete Role Assignment in subnet using Terraform Destroy command

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

Hi please can someone help me with this?
I created my infrastructure with my terraform config file to a subnet. The infrastructure creation was successful but when i want to clean up my resources using terraform destroy command, i have this error message:

Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Delete: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned
an error. Status=409 Code="ScopeLocked" Message="The scope '/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myVnet/subnets/mysubnet/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/*..*/' cannot perform delete operation because following scope(s) are locked: '/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myVnet' . Please remove the lock and try again."

Actually The VNet has a Delete lock Type set on it. And i do not want to be disabling the lock anytime i want to do terraform destroy.

Thank you for your suggestion on fixing this error
This is the provider version that i am using

```
azurerm = {
  source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
  version = "=2.97.0"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created a `Vnet` and `Subnet` within that `Vnet` using terraform.

**Case 1** : You want to delete the Vnet using terraform destroy. But VNet has a Delete lock Type set on it.

Answer : For Deleting the Vnet with Subnet using `terraform destroy` you should remove lock of deleting Vnet then you will delete using `terraform destroy`

**Case 2** : If you just want only to delete the `subnet` with in that vnet.

Answer : So delete the a particuler resource you can use terraform target. Terraform Destroy with `-target` flag allow you delete specific resource.

```
terraform destroy -target azurerm_subnet.subnetname
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. i am not deleting the VNet or the Subnet. The VNet and Subnet is already created by another team, so the team kept the delete Lock on it. I am using terraform to deploy my AKS cluster in the subnet.

Comment: To do this, i need to setup some role_assignment for my AKS managed identity so that it has permissions to deploy to the VNet and also to read and write to the route table in the VNet. When i run terraform destroy it is destroying this role_assignment resource and not the VNet or the Subnet. But this error shows up and as i already mentioned above, i am looking for a solution where i don't need to remove the lock from the VNet and after that run terraform destroy

Comment: Since your AKS cluster is using the existing subnet of Vnet and your vnet is in lock state to destroy the AKS cluster you need to remove the lock because your AKS cluster is accomplished using ip of that subnet